# dynamical textbox using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

hello im newbie at javascript and jquery.
i want to make a dynamical textbox using javascript which can add and remove a row. when i press add button, it works well. but when i pressed delete, it deleted all my table.

here is my javascript function and my php code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addProg(){

            document.getElementById("add_prog").innerHTML += "<tr><td><input type='date' class='form-control' name='tanggal[]'></td><td><input type='number' class='form-control' name='kuota[]'></td><td><input type='time' class='form-control' name='jam_mulai[]'></td><td><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='hapus()' value='Hapus'></tr>";
    }

    function hapus() 
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("add_prog");
        x.remove(x.tr);
    }
</script>
<div class="container">    
        <center><h3>Form Pendaftaran 
        </h3><center><br>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead><tr>
            <td> a </td>
            <td> b </td>
            <td> c </td>
            </tr></thead>

            <tbody id="add_prog">

            <tr id="1">
            <td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="tanggal[]"></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="kuota[]"></td>
            <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="jam_mulai[]"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="hapus()" value="Hapus"></td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
            </table>

            <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addProg()" value="Tambah">
```

i dont know how to delete spesific index that i want to deleted and write it in my script. can someone just please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `element.parentNode.parentNode.remove();` to remove element as you will have to find the `tr` element with respective clicked button

Try this:

```js
function addProg() {

  document.getElementById("add_prog").innerHTML += "<tr><td><input type='date' class='form-control' name='tanggal[]'></td><td><input type='number' class='form-control' name='kuota[]'></td><td><input type='time' class='form-control' name='jam_mulai[]'></td><td><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='hapus(this)' value='Hapus'></tr>";
}

function hapus(element) {
  element.parentNode.parentNode.remove(); //document.getElementById('add_prog').removeChild(element.parentNode.parentNode);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <center>
    <h3>Form Pendaftaran 
        </h3>
    <center>
      <br>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="add_prog">

          <tr id="1">
            <td>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" name="tanggal[]">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="kuota[]">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="time" class="form-control" name="jam_mulai[]">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="hapus(this)" value="Hapus">
            </td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>

      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addProg()" value="Tambah">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking to delete is the `lastChild` of your tbody element.

Here's some info on [lastChild](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_lastchild.asp).

Comment: i don't think so, i think i need find my row's index. i got the answer before. thanks for helping btw :)

Comment: @JulianaSucahya Sorry, I thought you wanted to delete last row only. Glad you got a good answer.